# error when running red5 application on windows

Tags: red5

I made very sample application for red5

I set **WEB-INF(red5-web.properties, red5-web.xml, web.xml)**

when I runnig the red.bat I view in the debug this  error code :

```
[INFO] [Launcher:/test] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefi
nitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-I
NF/red5-web.xml]
Exception in thread "Launcher:/test" org.springframework.beans.factory.xm
l.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 25 in XML document from ServletContext r
esource [/WEB-INF/red5-web.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXP
arseException; lineNumber: 25; columnNumber: 68; cvc-id.2: There are multiple oc
currences of ID value 'web.handler'
```

and my client can't connect to server :(

Answer (score 0):

from your description its impossible to say exactly what you've done.
You might better start to use for example the existing demo application that ship with every release.

Sebastian

Comment: well but the SaXParser Exception does tell you exactly where to look at: Line 25 in XML document from ServletContext r
esource [/WEB-INF/red5-web.xml] ... what does your red5-web.xml look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd                            
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="placeholderConfig" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="/WEB-INF/red5-web.properties" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="web.context" class="org.red5.server.Context"
        autowire="byType" />

    <bean id="web.scope" class="org.red5.server.WebScope"
         init-method="register">
        <property name="server" ref="red5.server" />
        <property name="parent" ref="global.scope" />
        <property name="context" ref="web.context" />
        <property name="handler" ref="web.handler" />
        <property name="contextPath" value="${webapp.contextPath}" />
        <property name="virtualHosts" value="${webapp.virtualHosts}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="web.handler" class="com.myapp.Application" />


</beans>
```

Comment: what is the name of the webapp? did you specify a custom name for it in the red5-web.properties?  The SAXParserException actually tells us to have two times the web.handler bean. Are you 100% sure the file you posted is the one deployed in the server? There might be also other webapps active that throw that exception.

Answer (score 0):

change the web.handler bean in your red5-web.xml file

```
<bean id="web.handler" class="com.myapp.Application" 
                       singleton="true" autowire="byName" />
```

Check the other bean names also. The error you posted says same ID used for two or more beans.